# RestKit 0.2 not logging

Tags: restkit, libcomponentlogging

I'm updating my app to use RestKit 0.2pre3, but on the process I lost the logging system that RestKit provides, it simply doesn't show anything anymore. I use cocoapods to install RestKit.

This is my Podfile

```
platform :ios , '5.1'

pod 'SSPullToRefresh'
pod 'MBProgressHUD'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'
pod 'TestFlightSDK'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'KISSmetrics'
pod 'CustomBadge'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK'
pod 'JSONKit'

pod 'LibComponentLogging-Core'
pod 'LibComponentLogging-LogFile'
pod 'LibComponentLogging-qlog'
pod 'LibComponentLogging-pods'
pod 'RestKit/Testing'
pod 'RestKit'

pod 'OHAttributedLabel'
```

And, of course, in my code I'm calling

```
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit", RKLogLevelTrace);
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/CoreData", RKLogLevelDebug);
```

I can even make successful request and get objects mapped, but I can't watch what is my server returning, how the mapping process is performed or anything and this is vital.

I think the problem is that something is misconfigured in LCL but I can't find any clues about it.

Any ideas where the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

After a long debugging I found that LCL now comes with a set of default configurations and on LCLLogFileConfig.h I had:

```
// Tell LCLLogFile whether it should mirror the log messages to stderr.
#define _LCLLogFile_MirrorMessagesToStdErr /* (BOOL) */                        \
    NO
```

I set it to **YES** and now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is caused by the following 2 pods in the Podfile:

```
pod 'LibComponentLogging-pods'
pod 'LibComponentLogging-LogFile'
```

The `LibComponentLogging-pods` pod causes an integration of RestKit's logging with the LibComponentLogging files which are installed via the Podfile, e.g. RestKit's log components can now be configured via the standard `lcl_configure`... configuration functions and RestKit will use the log writer which is configured via the Podfile (instead of its built-in log writer).

The `LibComponentLogging-LogFile` pod chooses the file-based log writer for LibComponentLogging. By default, this log writer doesn't mirror its messages to stderr. `_LCLLogFile_MirrorMessagesToStdErr` in `LCLLogFileConfig.h` can be used to change this behavior.